# Is there any way to run bash commands in Fortinet CLI?

Tags: linux, bash, firewall

Is there some way by which I can run bash commands in Fortinet or FortiOS? Or may be can I install bash in FortiOS? I wan to write a script to automate the configuration of Fortinet firewall through commands. I have figured out a way to run the commands one by one. Now I want those commands to bundle in one script (write a chef recipe) and run them on the Fortinet. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "fnsysctl" command that gives you access to a reduced set of bash commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real shell in FortiOS CLI, that is, no access to environment, no variables, no loops, no conditional statements, subroutines etc.
What you can do for repetitive configuration is to prepare a text file with the config statements and submit it via 'System > Advanced > Batch command' in the GUI. This will work even with a huge number of statements while just pasting them into the CLI (via SSH) can potentially choke. You can use any convenient script language for this, like bash, PS, python. Of course, this will only work if you know all settings in advance.

For real automation, you need to run a shell exterior to the Fortigate, pull status information etc. and generate these batch command files this way. The tool for this is called FortiManager (VM or hardware appliance). There is a REST API which you can use to get status information from FortiOS. Access to the documentation is via FortiDeveloper program.